# PostgreSQL Composite Types INSERT INTO SELECT Needs Casting

Tags: postgresql, composite-types

I want to INSERT some records from a query into a table that has a column with the type of a composite type.

```sql
create type ratio as (numerator bigint, denominator bigint);

create table my_ratios(id bigint, val ratio);
```

Inserting some values naturally works:

```sql
insert into my_ratios (id, val) values (1, (22, 7)) returning *;
```

But this does not:

```sql
-- this does not work:
insert into my_ratios 
SELECT 
   round(n::float / d * 100)
 , (n, d) as ratio -- cannot cast type record to ratio
FROM generate_series(21, 23) n
   , generate_series(6, 8) d
returning *;
```

I found that if I cast the rowtype to text and cast the text back to my composite type, then the query works. But this is quite ugly:

```sql
insert into my_ratios 
SELECT 
  round(n::float / d * 100)
, cast(cast((n, d) as text) as ratio) -- note two casts
FROM generate_series(21, 23) n
   , generate_series(6, 8) d
returning *;
```

Is there a special syntax that I can use here?

[SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c959e579edc16eeaf251e435da4b64de)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the tuple in the SELECT list:

```
SELECT round(n::float / d * 100), 
       (n, d)::ratio 
FROM ...
```

alternatively you can use `cast( (n, d) as ratio)`

---

Note that `(a,b) as ratio` just assigns an alias for the column. It has no implication on the actual data type of the column